# Wait for Timer/Process to finish before continuing

Tags: java, process, timer, jbutton

I have a function that flashes the border of a JButton which gets called multiple times in a row. I want the processes to continue only after the entirety of the function completes. Right now, the flashing starts for one button, then it will start for another before the flashing stopped for the first button. The function looks like the following which is in a class that extends JButton:

```
    public void flash() {
    final Timer timer = new Timer(7, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            alpha += increment;
            if (alpha >= 255) {
                alpha = 255;
                increment = -increment;
            }
            if (alpha <= 0) {
                alpha = 0;
                increment = -increment;
            }
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(81, 171, 112, alpha), 4));
        }
    });

    timer.start();

    final Timer delay = new Timer(
            2000,
            new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0), 0));
            timer.stop();
        }
    });
    delay.setRepeats(false);
    delay.setCoalesce(true);
    delay.start();
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to make your desired behavior clearer.  If by "processes" you mean any code in the current thread besides the `flash()` code, you could simply make `flash()` a blocking call.  However, I suspect what you really want is for every call to `flash()` to queue an event that must wait for all previous `flash()` calls to complete.  Thus allowing other code to continue and only delaying the `flash()` code.

Comment: BTW, `delay.setCoalesce(true);` isn't doing anything for you since `true` is the default setting.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#setCoalesce(boolean)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but you are right. I want all flash() calls to complete before calling the next one.

Answer (score 0):

A fundamental problem you have here is that there are multiple button objects.  That means each `flash()` lives in an independent object (since it isn't static).  That means each button has no idea if the others are flashing or not.

What you need is one place that does the flashing.  A place where whatever needs the flashing to happen can dump the work.  A place that knows about the buttons so it can manipulate their borders.  Lets call it the `flasherQueue`.

A static member could be used for this but a more flexible design would inject the single `flasherQueue` object into each of your button objects as they are constructed.  Each button knowing about flasherQueue is only required if it's the buttons that decide when to flash.

At this point you are free to make your buttons `flash()` method into a blocking call.  Whatever you have decide to flash a button simply passes a reference to the button to the `flasherQueue`.  The `flasherQueue`, looping in it's own thread, grinds through any buttons it's been given in order, waiting for each to finish flashing.

Done this way you should only ever have at most one flashing button at a time and should be free to process other events so your GUI should repaint.

This is really a degenerative form of [producer / consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem#Without_semaphores_or_monitors).  As long as you have only one consumer calling a buttons `flash()` only one button will flash at a time.  You'll probably be able to make use of java's [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) for your data structure behind `flasherQueue`.

Comment: Sounds great! Some of that is definitely over my head, but I think I got the gist of what you are saying to do. There's quite a few things I'd have to look into. I was making a Java Applet game for a class I'm taking at college. I turned in the project and ultimately found something that 'worked'. It wasn't ideal though and I am definitely thinking of rewriting a lot of the program over again because there are way too many classes that overlap one another. Thanks again! I'll keep this in mind this summer as I rewrite the game!